# How can I give my element height: 100%?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

http://cristianfertea.ro/event/magie-si-management/

I have a question for all resolutions
I have an iframe element that fail to make it responsive.

```html
<center>
  <iframe style="border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0 auto; display:block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="http://slideful.com/v20150404_2118785928188675_ijf.htm"  frameborder="0">
  </iframe>
</center>
```

I want to be seen as fully item ... currently look as displayed.
Perhaps something is obstructing so not to see completely.

http://i57.tinypic.com/2keydg.jpg

How can i solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your code you have `100%px` for `height`, remove the `px`.

Comment: sorry but even if I accidentally delete the problem remains

Comment: The 100% will take the height from the parent element. Make sure your parent element is full height too.

Comment: I looked after these things but I realize that is not the parent element.
I studied many times before code to post this problem

Comment: Add more details about the issue ... better in Fiddle which explains the issue precisely.

Comment: I do not know what more I could add, just my Iframe is not seen anywhere ... and I want to give it 100%.
If you add in fidle code will work there, I have a problem on my site not generally

Answer (score 1):

The page referred by `iframe` tag is occupying 100% of container. 
The apparent problem is that, the page referred by `iframe` tag has insufficient content to fill the screen. So your page, shows a lot of empty.

To resolve this issue, you have to change content of `http://slideful.com/v20150404_2118785928188675_ijf.htm` so that, it will occupy entire container.

Comment: unfortunately I did not quite understand what to do ... I am beginner and need a code example to understand.
thanks anyway

Comment: @Gigel. You need modify code of `http://slideful.com/v20150404_2118785928188675_ijf.htm` to make it's content occupy entire screen.

Answer (score 0):

Your element's parent needs to have height:100% as well. If it's does not work, check the parent of the parent ... even body and html.